# Adding animation between splashScreen And home screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I have made a project in which i have added a splash screen by adding default.png file in the project.

the issue is the home home screen appears after the splash screen without any animation where as i want to add a slide effect.

How that can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` you could add something like this:

```
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20, 320, 460)];//if you don't have the status bar set y=0 and height=480
 splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
 [window addSubview:splashView];
 [window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
 [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
 //slide to left
 splashView.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 20, 320, 460);
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

On your root view contoller, you could display the Default.png image in a `UIImageView`. Then, on `viewDidAppear`, you can trigger an animation to move a UIView (with your main content) that starts off screen, into place.

Answer (score 1):

This is against Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5).

> Because users are likely to switch among applications frequently, you should make every effort to **cut launch time to a minimum**, and you should design a launch image that **downplays the experience rather than drawing attention to it**.

But if you still want to do it, you should do the following instead of just displaying the home screen in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

1. Display a UIImageView that contains the splash screen image.
2. Display the real home screen with an animation after some time.